# TeamCity Rest API - Run Custom Build

Tags: teamcity

I am trying to trigger a custom build on a project passing in a specific modificationId as mentioned [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Accessing+Server+by+HTTP?focusedCommentId=36012180#comment-36012180).

e.g `httpAuth/action.html?add2Queue=bt27&modificationId=3605`

This works great. However I need to be able to get the modificationId of the last know successful build. I cannot see or find any mention of this in the rest api docs.

I am able to retrieve the buildId of the last successful build but the modificationId is 
not included

e.g `httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:bt27/builds/status:SUCCESS/number`

Does anybody know how to get a list of modificationIds from the rest api?

Comment: Do you happen to know whether it's possible to trigger a custom build and pass in custom parameters to said build, to override default values?

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the builds for a particular project or build config like this:

```
http://yourserver/app/rest/buildTypes/id:your_project_id
```

You can filter these results to only show the most recent successful build like this:

```
http://yourserver/app/rest/buildTypes/id:your_project_id/?count=1&status=SUCCESS
```

Use a script to load the href from the build returned by the above url and you can get the "lastChanges" element, which always contains the ID of the last change.

You can then send the link below to trigger a build that will only include changes up to that ID like this:

```
http://yourserver/app/rest/action.html?add2Queue=your_project_id&modificationId=000000
```

NOTE:
The ID attribute in the lastChanges element is the one you want to use as the modificationID.  This is not the actual change ID from your VCS though.  This is an internal Team City ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of modifications using url
http://buildserver/httpAuth/app/rest/changes. You can find more info in REST API [documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin).